# Two seemingly contradict ways of obtaining this limit

Tags: limits

The limit is :

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)= \lim_{x\to 0}( \frac{2}{x}-\frac{(x^2+1)\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}{x^2})
$$

### method 1:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{2}{x}-\frac{\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}{x^2})=\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{2}{x}-\frac{\frac{2}{1-x^2}}{2x})=-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2}{x}\to -\infty
$$

### method 2:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x-(x^2+1)\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}{x^2} =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x-\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2-\frac{2}{1-x^2}}{2x} =0
$$

Question is which is right, why the other is incorrect? please help me point out the error.

Comment: where is $\ (x^2+1)$ in your first method?

Comment: I would say that *both* are incorrect. **Do not set $x=0$ in parts of the expression while keeping $x$ elsewhere**. Going to the limit must occur for **all** $x$ at the same time!

Comment: @Mosk I omit it cause $x\to 0$

Comment: @A.G. How did you obtain $-2$? I'm interested.

Comment: @buzhidao Since $\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+o(x^2)$ we get $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=2x+o(x^2)$. Substitute, simplify and go to the limit. (I did it fast, cannot guarantie $-2$)

Comment: @A.G. You've made a mistake. it should be $2x+o(x^4)$. Thus it is zero. Still my question is not answered. I've already know the method 2 is correct answer before I asked this question. Pleas leave comment on method 1.

Comment: The first is quite wrong. The second has gaps in the explanation, and implicitly uses techniques that can yield wrong answers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Please comment further, why quite wrong, what techniques used in second is dangerous? This is what I am asking this question for.

Comment: @buzhidao how you have removed $(x^2+1)$ in second method this is  wrong if you are thinking it is equal to one than what if here is $x+1$. the  better way is to use taylor series in such cases.

Comment: It has been answered. For example in the second you replaced the $x^2$ in $1+x^2$ by $0$. In this case that can be justified, but in similar problems it cannot.  Also at the very end of the second you essentially asserted that the difference between two terms that blow up has limit $0$. That is in general false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method is definitely wrong. Essentially what you are doing is saying that $\lim_{x\to 0}(a(x) - b(x)) = \lim_{x\to 0} a(x) - \lim_{x\to 0} b(x)$. This is valid only if each individual limit on the right exists.

For method 2, as A.G. pointed out, you can't just get rid of $x^2+1$. Instead, you should note that as $x\to 0$,
$$\frac{2x-(x^2+1)\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}{x^2}\to \frac{0}{0},$$
so that L'Hopital's Rule applies. Differentiating, you get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x-(x^2+1)\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}{x^2}
   = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2 - 2x\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) - (x^2+1)\frac{2}{1-x^2}}{2x}.
$$
As $x\to 0$, both numerator and denominator again go to zero; applying L'Hopital again gives
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-2\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x} - 2x\frac{2}{1-x^2} - 2x\cdot\frac{2}{1-x^2} - (x^2+1)\cdot\frac{4x}{(x^2-1)^2}}{2}.$$
This limit can be evaluated by simply setting $x=0$, giving $0$ for the limit.

It's important to remember what A.G. said. When evaluating a limit, you can't arbitrarily set a variable to a value in one place and leave it alone somewhere else.

Comment: *This is valid only if each individual limit on the right exists.* This wakes me up, thank you very much ! Also thank you for your warning: **When evaluating a limit, you can't arbitrarily set a variable to a value in one place and leave it alone somewhere else**, I think I will expand around $x=0$, this is a perfectly fine method I think.

Answer (score 2):

Easy algebra gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{2}{x}-\frac{(x^{2}+1)\ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) }{x^{2}} &=&%
\frac{2}{x}-\frac{\ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) }{x^{2}}-\ln \left( 
\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)  \\
&=&\frac{x+x-\ln (1+x)+\ln (1-x)}{x^{2}}-\ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) 
\\
&=&\left( \frac{x-\ln (1+x)}{x^{2}}\right) +\left( \frac{x+\ln (1-x)}{x^{2}}%
\right) -\ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
By L'hospital rule twice, it follows that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\ln (1+x)}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x+\ln (1-x)}{x^{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{2}{x}-\frac{(x^{2}+1)\ln \left( \frac{1+x}{%
1-x}\right) }{x^{2}}\right) =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-0=0.\ \ \ \blacksquare 
\end{equation*}

Comment: so you make the limit in three parts, each of them is well defined limit. Nice